# iOS facebook auth sso:true

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with facebook Auth on users that their token was expired.
The apps loops to facebook and back a lot of time with no success. 
When debugging the fb token I have from those people I get the following result :

what seems to be very wired. is that all the users that have a problem. 
Their Metadata is {"sso":true}
where is people with no problem their Metadata is {"sso": ios}
what does sso:true means?

"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.

details:
Metadata  {"sso":true}
Issued  Unknown
Expires Never
Valid   False
Origin  Mobile Web Faceweb